# Why is a certain matrix transformation is $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix transformation $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, why does it go from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, when it squishes the plane into a line?

Comment: There is nothing in the word "transformation" that implies "onto".

Comment: The line $\{(0,y) : y\in \mathbb R\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ so this map does map $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of the point $(a,b) $ is $$f (a,b)=(0a+1.b,0a+0b)=(b,0) $$

all images are in the line whose equation is $y=0$.

$f $ is from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ but $f (\mathbb R^2)=\{(x,0) : x\in \mathbb R\} $ is a line.

$f $ is not surjective.